# How do i search for the youtube trending titles?

Tags: python, web-scraping

So im trying to get the titles for the trending page on youtube with beautifulsoup. I'm really really new to doing stuff with python, beautifulsoup, and stackexchange in general so sorry for any errors and stuff.

I've tried watching a few videos but i can't find much on this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                             
from urllib.request import urlopen                                                                                                        
import requests                                                                                                                           

url = 'https://youtube.com'                                                                                                               
rq = requests.get(url).text                                                                                                               
soup = BeautifulSoup(rq, 'html.parser')                                                                                                   


trending = soup.find_All('div', id="dismissable")                                                                                         


print(trending)
```

I wanted to get the html for the youtube trending so that i could then search for each specific title. I got a null thing though. It was either [] or None.

Comment: don't you want `https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending` as your base URL? Also, in the future, use the `{}` tool on the edit menu on selected text so it will format as code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')#.text.encode("utf-8")

csv_file = open('YouTube Trending Titles on 12-30-18.csv','w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Title', 'Description'])

for content in soup.findAll('div', class_= "yt-lockup-content"):
    #print (content)
    try:
        title = content.h3.a.text
        print(title)

        description = content.find('div', class_="yt-lockup-description yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2").text
        print(description)

    except Exception as e:
        description = None

    print('\n')
    csv_writer.writerow([title.encode('utf8') , description.encode('utf8') ])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: This will print title and description of trending